# Is it possible to have multiple activities listen with SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener

Tags: android, android-preferences

I have two activities, my `MainActivity` and my `SettingsActivity` (which instantiates the `PreferenceFragment`.

I would like both activities to do:

```
final SharedPreferences mPrefs = 
        getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.shared_prefs), 
                             Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
mPrefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(mListener);
```

Where each has its own implementation of `mListener` (a `SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener`) .

What I am seeing is that only one of the of the `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` is triggered.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to have multiple listeners at once as seen here:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/master/core/java/android/app/SharedPreferencesImpl.java#186

It is likely your problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a base instance of Application class instead of current Activity to store your Listener.
It really depends on what you want to do.